# Login with Facebook using Stack Exchange Android App

Tags: support, android-app, facebook

I just downloaded the Stack Exchange app from Play Store and when I tried to login there was no option to login with Facebook, am I missing something? Is it connected with OpenID?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing your login screen looks like this:

[image: no facebook installed]

But if you have the [official Facebook app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) installed, the login screen looks like this:

[image: with Facebook app installed]

Per [Is Facebook an OpenID provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827997/is-facebook-an-openid-provider), Facebook is not an OpenID provider. So you'll need to install the official Facebook app to login via Facebook in the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: Thank you, that was really the case.

Comment: +1 Yep, same here. Installed fb app and new login option appeared.

Comment: I hope they fix this so it uses a Web view like all other apps do.

Comment: I have the official facebook app, but then also I am unable to login with facebook