# Unable to login to Stack Overflow app with Facebook login

Tags: bug, android-app, facebook

I am solely registered via Facebook and I am trying to login to the Stack Overflow app but the option to login to Facebook does not appear:

> [image: Faulty login screen]

My problem is almost identical to that posted here:

[Login with Facebook using Stack Exchange Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230998/login-with-facebook-using-stack-exchange-android-app/302696?noredirect=1#comment984492_302696)

except that I do have the Facebook app installed and logged into. I have tried reinstalling the Facebook app but this has not helped. Since I have registered with Facebook this means I am unable to use the app.

Comment: This post is related to [SO android-app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app) and it may suitable to [SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I think you may be right, unless the login procedure relating to Facebook is the same across all the websites in which case it won't be restricted to SO.

Comment: The SO app is not the SE app. If you want a more stable app with less bugs, use the SE app. It still got bugs, but less than the new app since they fixed some over the years.

Comment: @ShadowWizard BTW, why SE App for iOS has so many available features, less bugs, good UI than SE Android app? Any specific reason?

Comment: @JaideepKhare yes, because the iOS app got a dedicated developer who spent tons of time and efforts on fixing bugs and adding new features. The sole developer of the android app was also the mobile app team leader and suffered from personal problems, so he was not able to spend any time programming.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So no hope in future, for a 'Very Nice' SE Android App?

Comment: @JaideepKhare true. Development of both apps has been stopped, the team disbanded.

Comment: That's a shame, although SE app seems to be very good and cover multiple websites, so specific SO app is probably redundant anyways. Would be nice to have known this before though lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment written by Shadow Wizard, I have managed to access the Stack Exchange app with little hassle as the option to login with Facebook was available. My account as registered using Facebook did not have an email associated with it and so was not initially recognised, but after adding an email through the website separately I was able to access it. I am still not able to access the Stack Overflow app however, so I will post on the Stack Overflow Meta website.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, we can keep this now as reference for others with the same issue.